# How to rename a column name to a new value in a dataframe if the column names are dynamic

Tags: regex, pandas, python-2.7

I have csv file with column names changing based on month and year but has keyword like 'sales' 'product' etc. Is there a way to rename the column to a fixed value using python rename by searching the keyword
Sample column names would be 2019 May sales Tv, 2018 April sales Fridge
eg

nil

```
df_nw = df.rename(df.filter(like='Sales').columns.values
```

Current data:

```
column1 column2 2019AprilSalesTV 2018ActualSalesTV
X        BBBB       7766              60
Y        CCCC         10              20
Z        LLLLL        60              65
K        TTTTT         10             67
```

New Data:

```
column1 column2    Sales          ActualSales
X        BBBB       7766              60
Y        CCCC         10              20
Z        LLLLL        60              65
K        TTTTT         10             67
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
> clean_colname = lambda x: re.sub(r'(^\w+(?<!Actual))(Sales)', r'\2',
                                   re.sub(r'^\d+|TV$', r'', x))

> df_nw.rename(clean_colname, axis=1) 

        column2  Sales  ActualSales
column1                            
X          BBBB   7766           60
Y          CCCC     10           20
Z         LLLLL     60           65
K         TTTTT     10           67
```

Comment: Thank you this helps! Now for me there is another set of column names as           2019 current may XXX and 2019 June upcoming. When I apply this filter it is giving me current  may and June upcoming. The months are not getting trimmed off. I used below code. Can you please suggest the changes  .

Comment: clean_colname = lambda x: re.sub(r'(^\w+(?<!Current)) (Current)', r'\2', re.sub(r'^\d+|XXX$', r'', x))
clean_colname_2 = lambda x: re.sub(r'(^\w+(?<!Upcoming)) (Upcoming)', r'\2',re.sub(r'^\d', r'', x))
df4=df3.rename(clean_colname, axis=1) 
df5=df4.rename(clean_colname_2,axis=1)